# How to calculate discount value and moneytransfer using ajax and jquery and display in website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, discount

Hi I have been fighting this problem for over 3 day's now. I'll try to explain what i would like to do.

1. Enters a discountcode
2. Check validity code
3. Check if value is % of a value
4. Give back value using Ajax
5. Calculat final price (normalprice - discount + moneytransercosts)
6. Display price in page

voucher1: stackoverflow1250 => 12,50
 
voucher2: stackoverflow50   => 50% 
example: http://www.gitaartabs.nl/aanmelden.html?ref=plus&discount

Javascript on the page aanmelden.html

```
// Select subscription (Dutch -> abonnement)
// Globals
        var discount_value; 
        var discount_value_amount; 
        var abonnement; 
        var moneytransfer; 
        var totalprice;
        var displayprice = totalprice;

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#username").change(function() {
        var usr = $("#username").val();
        if(usr.length >= 4)
        {
        $("#status").html('<img src="js/username_checker/loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "js/username_checker/check.php",
            data: "username="+ usr,
            success: function(msg){
                $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
                    if(msg == 'OK')
                    {
                        $("#username").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                        $("#username").addClass("object_ok");
                        $(this).html('&nbsp;<img src="js/username_checker/tick.gif" align="absmiddle">');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#username").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                        $("#username").addClass("object_error");
                        $(this).html(msg);
                    }
                });
            }
          });
        }
        else{
            $("#status").html('<font color="red">&nbsp;Minimum <strong>4</strong> characters.</font>');
            $("#username").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
            $("#username").addClass("object_error");
        }
    }); 

$("#discountcodeid").change(function() {
        var discountcodeid = $("#discountcodeid").val();
        var discount_value = discount.val;
        $("#discount").html('<img src="js/username_checker/loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Coupon valideren ...');
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "classes/discountcheck.php",
            data: "discountcodeid="+ discountcodeid, 
            success: function(msg){
                $("#discount").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
                    if(msg == 'OK')
                    {
                        $("#discountcodeid").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                        $("#discountcodeid").addClass("object_ok");
                        $(this).html('&nbsp;<img src="js/username_checker/tick.gif" align="absmiddle">');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#discountcodeid").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                        $("#discountcodeid").addClass("object_error");
                        $(this).html(msg);
                    }
                });
            }
          });
    alert ("Gefeliciteerd je krijgt " + discount + " euro korting"); 
    }); 
}); //end document.ready function

function selectAbonnement(id)
{
    $("#type-abonnement-" + id).attr("checked", true);
    if (id == 1) { //gratis
        $("#paymentOptions").hide('fast');
        $("#discountcode").hide('fast');
        $("#adres").hide('fast');
        $("#naam").hide('fast');
        $("#aanmeldengtplus").hide('fast');
        $("#aanmeldengtgratis").show('fast');
        $("#instrument").show('fast');
        $("#invoiceamount").hide('fast');
        $("#paymentlogos").hide('fast');
        $("#displayprice").hide('fast');

    } else { //betaald
        $("#paymentOptions").show('fast');
        $("#discountcode").show('fast');
        $("#adres").show('fast');
        $("#naam").show('fast');
        $("#aanmeldengtplus").show('fast');
        $("#aanmeldengtgratis").hide('fast');
        $("#instrument").hide('fast');
        $("#invoiceamount").show('fast');
        $("#paymentlogos").show('fast');
        $("#displayprice").show('fast');
        $("#inloggen").hide('fast');


        if (id == 2) { // 1mnd abonnement
            $("#invoiceamount2").show('fast');
            $("#invoiceamount3").hide('fast');
            $("#invoiceamount4").hide('fast');
            this.abonnement=24.95;
        }
        if (id == 3) { // 3mnd abonnement
            $("#invoiceamount3").show('fast');
            $("#invoiceamount2").hide('fast');
            $("#invoiceamount4").hide('fast');
            this.abonnement=62.50;
        }
        if (id == 4) { // 6mnd abonnement
            $("#invoiceamount4").show('fast');
            $("#invoiceamount2").hide('fast');
            $("#invoiceamount3").hide('fast');
            this.abonnement=99.50;
        }
    }
}

function paymentChange(payment)
{
    if (payment == 'ideal') {
        $("#paymentIdeal").show('fast');
        $("#paymentPaypal").hide('fast');
        $("#paymentMoneytransfer").hide('fast');
        this.moneytransfer = 0;
    } else if (payment == 'paypal') {
        $("#paymentIdeal").hide('fast');
        $("#paymentPaypal").show('fast');
        $("#paymentMoneytransfer").hide('fast');
        moneytransfer = 0;
    } else if (payment == 'moneytransfer') {
        $("#paymentIdeal").hide('fast');
        $("#paymentPaypal").hide('fast');
        $("#paymentMoneytransfer").show('fast');
        this.moneytransfer = 2.50;

        // CALCULATION OF TOTAL PRICE
        this.totalprice = this.abonnement;

        if(discount_value > 0){ // KORTINGPERCENTAGE
        totalprice = abonnement + moneytransfer - (abonnement * (discount_value/100));
        }
        else if (discount_value_amount > 0){ // WAARDE KORTING
        totalprice = abonnement + moneytransfere - discount_value_amount;
        }
        else{
        totalprice = abonnement + moneytransfer ;
        }
        alert ("De Totaalprijs wordt (ivm administratiekosten)  " + totalprice + " Euro.");

    }
}


//-->
</script>
```

Where to place the totalprice

```
<div id="invoiceamount2" style="display:none;">
    <br />
    Product: <span class="priceproduct">1 maand Gitaartabs Plus</span><br /><br />
    <span class="pricevoor">Totaalbedrag: &euro; <span id="totalprice">24,95</span></span><br>
</div>
<div id="invoiceamount3" style="display:none;">
    <br />
    Product: <span class="priceproduct">3 maanden Gitaartabs Plus</span><br /><br />
    <span class="pricevoor">Totaalbedrag:  &euro; <span id="totalprice">62,50</span></span>
     <span class="pricevan">(Normaal &euro; 74,85</span>)<br>
    <span class="pricebesparing">Je bespaart &euro; 12,35! (15% korting)</span>
</div>
<div id="invoiceamount4" style="display:none;">
    <br />
    Product: <span class="priceproduct">3 maanden Gitaartabs Plus</span><br /><br />
    <span class="pricevoor">Totaalbedrag: &euro; <span id="totalprice">99,50</span></span>
    <span class="pricevan">(Normaal &euro; 149,70</span>)<br>
    <span class="pricebesparing">Je bespaart &euro; 50,20!  (32% korting)</span>
</div>
<br />
<hr>    
    <h2>De volgende stap - Betaling (payment)</h2>
<hr>    
<div id=betaling> <? /* IF TOTAL = 0 { GRATIS } */ ?>
<div>
    <br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="paymentname" value="ideal" checked="checked" onchange="paymentChange('ideal');">iDeal</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="paymentname" value="paypal" onchange="paymentChange('paypal');">PayPal</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="paymentname" value="moneytransfer" onchange="paymentChange('moneytransfer');">Overboeking (+ &euro; 2,<sup>50</sup>)</label>
    <br /><br />
</div>
```

The check.php gives back this.

```
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_check);
    $discount_value = $row['discount_value'];
    $discount_value_amount = $row['discount_value_amount'];

    if(mysql_num_rows($sql_check))
    { 
        if($discount_value > 0 )
        {
            // discount is percentage (10%)
            echo $discount_value;
        }
        else if($discount_value_amount > 0 )
        {
            // discount is value (24,95)
            echo $discount_value_amount; 

        }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "&nbsp;<font color=\"red\">To bad this code is not correct.</font>";
    }
```

I realy hope s.o. could help me break this puzzle :)
Best regards and thanks alot!

Jan

Comment: I am a little confused by your code... in `$(this).html(msg);` what were you expecting `this` to refer to?

Comment: perhaps that's my (non) knowledge of var and global vars. I have read that this. is the same as window. to use inside of outside the funtion. But please shoot at it if you like so i could change things

Comment: The value of `this` inside any callback/function supplied to a method (like ajax) depends completely on what the method says it will be. For an Ajax call it is probably something to do with the ajax call (I think it is the value of the `context:` setting passed to ajax). If you want to reference screen elements, you need to save them to a local var before you call the ajax method or pass them via the ajax `context:` setting. You can then reference them from inside the success method.